# ofstream - detect if file has been deleted between open and close

Tags: c++, linux, file

I'm wriiting a logger on linux.
the logger open a file on init.
and write to that file descriptor as the program run.
if the log file will be deleted after the file descriptor was created,
no exception/error  will be detected .
i have tried:

```
out.fail()
!out.is_open()
```

i have google this and find this post .
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread23244.html

so i understand now that even if the file was deleted by using rm. it is still exist, it was simply unlinked.
 
what is the best way to handele this?
1. this is a log application so performance is an issue , i don't want to use stat() on every write
2. i don't care if some of the line in the log files will be missing at the start 
3. the user is allowed to delete the log file, to start fresh .the logger should reopen the file.

Comment: What function do you use for writing to file?
E.g. for fwrite you can test return result. And if size differs from expected, then reopen (create) file..

Comment: @ Dyatlov test the result wont help , because the file exist it was just unlinked , the write sucssed.so does the checking of the  filesize , Thanks

Comment: I came across this while investigating the same issue, except the process doing the deletion was logrotate -- my case is much cleaner to fix -- logrotate has an option -- copytruncate -- which will solve this issue with logging by not deleting the file at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files are '[unlinked](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/unlink.html)' by `rm`.

A file can have many names.  When it has no names left, and nobody has it open, then it is reclaimed by the file system and the space it occupies can be reused.

Linux has an API for 'watching' files called [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), but this is inviting complexity and race conditions.

So the bigger question is, who else is deleting this file when it is run, and why?  Convince them not to!

Comment: our system lets the user delete the log files so he can start fresh , this is how our system work and i can't change this :(

Comment: then you need to provide a procedure for the user to send a 'truncate' message to the logger, rather than doing a manual delete on the file-system.  You need to change something, the current approach won't work by design.

Comment: inotify is probably the best way to solve this, even if it is complicated.

Comment: Prevent the user from deleting the log file (can supply pointy things if neccessary). To reset/clear the logfile do "cat /dev/null > logfile".

Comment: > So the bigger question is, who else is deleting this file when it is run, and why? Convince them not to!

It really isn't. This is what sop for logrotate is.

Answer (score 1):

You've stated in comments that the reason for this is that the user is allowed to delete the log file, and in this case you want the application to start writing a fresh one in its place.

The traditional UNIX mechanism to handle this is to have your program install a signal handler (often for `SIGHUP`, since that otherwise makes no sense for a daemon).  The signal handler includes code to make the program close and reopen the log file.

The user is then instructed that after they delete the log file, they need to send a `SIGHUP` to the program.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way to handle this is to try to write to the log. If the write fails (most of the time it won't) then you need to find out why. At that point you can do things like using stat to see if the log is still there - if it is, you have some sort of disk full or permission error, which may be difficult or impossible to recover from, if it isn't, re-open and re-try the write.

Comment: @Neil rm doesn't realy delete the file it simple unlink it. The file is still exist and used by the application , the writing will succeed.
so checking for error won't help

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread but it still popped up when I had the same question, so I thought I contribute with a more modern answer that works for me.

I am using the function [std::filesystem::exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) (C++17 feature, and in experimental_filesystem for C++14). It returns `true` if the file exists, `false` when it doesn't, and it does return `false` even when the file existed and is "unlinked" by rm.

So my program will always check if the file exists before writing to it. It doesn't create any noticeable CPU overhead in my case, and I write about 50KB per seconds in batches of 20 to 255 bytes, and it does the check sometimes up to 500 times per second. Tested quite a lot and never had issues with it.

In general, the filesystem library for C++17 is awesome and removes so much of the headache that C legacy code was creating. Much simpler and clearer to use IMHO.